# "There is an apple and an orange" or "there are an apple and an orange"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, there-is

> - There is an apple and an orange on the table.
> - There are an apple and an orange on the table.

Which is grammatical?

Comment: Yes, "or". Some people use one, and some the other.

Comment: This *exact same* example has been posted before. Please search the site before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are is preferred with and.
Is is used with or.

Comment: No, not necessarily true. "There **is** a church **and** a school in the local village." "There **is** milk **and** eggs in the fridge"

Comment: Not necessarily not necessarily true. "There are a church and a school in the local village." "There are milk and eggs in the fridge." Surely the deciding factor amongst non-prescriptivists is whether A and B are seen as separate items in a list, or (A + B) is seen as a composite: 'Bacon and eggs are too expensive for most people to be able to afford in Elbonia.' / 'Bacon and eggs is on the menu.'